# Using Ruby in Mac OS terminal: unterminated string meets end of file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I have been going through a Ruby tutorial on Mac OS X 10.10.1, running Ruby 2.0.0p481. My program is saved as "calc.rb".

When I am asked to run a basic string:

```
puts 'i like' + 'apples.'
```

the terminal will return either:

```
calc.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
```

or:

```
calc.rb:1: unterminated string meets end of file
```

This is seemingly at random. I'm unsure how to move forward. I also had this problem for around 30 minutes just trying to run a basic string like:

```
puts 'hello, world!'
```

Comment: How are you running the file?

Comment: @Brennan saving a textedit file, then:

    cd ~/Desktop
    ruby calc.rb

Comment: Are you running `cd ~/Desktop ruby calc.rb` all in one line?

Comment: @Brennan hi, no, sorry - first time using this website and getting to grips with commenting. running cd ~/Desktop first then ruby calc.rb on the next line

Comment: And that one line is the only thing in your file?

Comment: Ah, just saw the part about textedit. It's very possible that textedit is causing your problems. Try it with a text editor instead of processor. I recommend Sublime Text. To ensure that this is actually the problem, you can write up the code really quickly using vim.

Comment: just reopened terminal, did exactly as i said with 'i like ' + 'apples.' saved as the only thing in my file and recieved "calc.rb:1:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `‘' for main:Object (NameError)".

Comment: thanks, i have sublime text and will retry with that

Comment: By default TextEdit converts quotes to curly-quotes. You can turn that off, but that won't make TextEdit become a better editor. The recommendation for Sublime Text is good. If you're programming in multiple environments, I'd recommend learning vim or emacs. Both have versions available on every OS you're likely to encounter, and all will behave consistently.

Comment: yeah, turns out it was textedit's quotes that were messing everything up. such a minor thing. that explanation helps me a lot. thanks, i'll use sublime text from now on!